# What is maximum limit space per table in oracle 10g and 11g?

Tags: oracle

I have a production table. The table is updating and deleting rows daily. So want to know about how many space allowed per table in oracle 10g and 11g? If exceed the limit how we fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Practically, there is no limit.  At least not one that any human is likely to hit.

If you want to be pedantic, a bigfile tablespace can be up to 32 TB in size if the database is using 8k blocks or 128 TB if the database is using 32k blocks.  A table can have up to 1024k partitions.  Each partition could be in a different tablespace but you can only have 64k tablespaces.  So if you have 64k partitions and each partition in a separate bigfile tablespace with nothing else in the tablespace, you could have up to 128 TB * 64k = 8192 PB = 8 EB (exabytes).  That's roughly 1,000 times all the data stored in the Library of Congress.  If your table is that large, you've done something extraordinarily wrong.

Each version of the database has a couple of sections in the Oracle Reference on the [physical limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits002.htm#i287915) and on the [logical limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032) of the database that you can use to answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: I need 1,001 completely different versions of the Library of Congress. I guess I'll have to install a second database :)

Comment: Nice Explain Justin cave.This is very useful for us